# Run univariate regression between each variable python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression

I have a daraframe with 49 columns, I want to see if there some relation between columns, i.e. run simple linear regression between each columns. Expected ouput should be matrix with columns and rows named same and filled by regression coefficient.

e.g. `df`:

```
bar foo too ten
1   2   3   4
4   5   6   5
7   8   9   6
```

Output:

```
     bar             foo             too              ten
bar  r_coef(bar,bar) r_coef(bar,foo) r_coef(bar,too)  r_coef(bar,ten)
foo  r_coef(foo,bar) r_coef(foo,foo) r_coef(foo,too)  r_coef(foo,ten)
too  r_coef(too,bar) r_coef(too,foo) r_coef(too,too)  r_coef(too,ten)
ten  r_coef(ten,bar) r_coef(ten,foo) r_coef(ten,too)  r_coef(ten,ten)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can use `np.polyfit`. You have a first degree polynomial (`y = mx + b`) so set degree to 1 and you want to get the intercept value (`b`).

As @mozway suggests you, use `corr` but with a custom method:

```
# [1] is the intercept value, [0] is the slope
r_coef = lambda x, y: np.polyfit(x, y, deg=1)[1]

out = df.corr(method=r_coef)
print(out)

# Output
          bar       foo  too       ten
bar  1.000000  1.000000  2.0  3.666667
foo  1.000000  1.000000  1.0  3.333333
too  2.000000  1.000000  1.0  3.000000
ten  3.666667  3.333333  3.0  1.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you simply want to use [`corr`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html):

```
df.corr()
```

output:

```
     bar  foo  too  ten
bar  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
foo  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
too  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
ten  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

##### less ambiguous example:

```
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(4,4)),
                  columns=['bar', 'foo', 'too', 'ten'])

df.corr()
          bar       foo       too       ten
bar  1.000000 -0.701808  0.595832 -0.211943
foo -0.701808  1.000000 -0.911949 -0.547439
too  0.595832 -0.911949  1.000000  0.551369
ten -0.211943 -0.547439  0.551369  1.000000
```

Comment: I'm interested to see how one variable affects other, while `corr` is simply shows the degree of a relationship..

Comment: @ker_laeda86 I don't get your comment, isn't the output what you expected? The correlation coefficient)

Comment: Sorry, let me clarify: since regression is `Y = a + bX`, I want to get the `a`, not a correlation coefficient. I'm wondering how to loop regression between variables and store those `a`.

Comment: IIUC, you want to get the intercept value, don't you?

Comment: Oops I hadn't seen this comment